Report error about not found source "mongodb", though sbt assembly jar has mongo-spark-connector v10
I would like to use spark dataframe to connect to the mongodb, and make the parquet files. I config mongo-spark-connector v10.2.2 in the sbt file, and it work at the local. However, on the production, the spark application would report java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: mongodb. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html. (All the exteral library would be built into a assembly.jar)
I have checked the assembly.jar, sbt indeed downloads the connector jar. Is there anything that I miss?
[add. info]
Here's the Spark version: 3.1.3, and mongo-spark-connector v10.2.2
Spark application use client mode.
I manually downloaded the mongo-spark-connector.jar and used system property command like java -cp etc::/opt/app/lib/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-10.2.2.jar:/opt/app/lib/assembly-1.0.jar that it would work.

update
Here's my build.sbt file.
name := "app"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.10"
lazy val sparkVersion = "3.1.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.12" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-avro_2.12" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-avro" % "1.12.2",
  "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "10.2.2"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF") && x.endsWith(".SF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF") && x.endsWith(".RSA") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF") && x.endsWith(".DSA") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF") && x.endsWith(".TXT") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

Here's the shell script for starting the application.
#!/bin/bash

CLASSPATH="";

for jar_file in /opt/app/lib/*.jar; do
    if [[ $jar_file != /opt/app/lib/app*.jar ]]; then
        CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$jar_file";
    fi
done;

for jar_file in /opt/app/lib/app*.jar; do
    CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$jar_file";
done;

CLASSPATH="etc:$CLASSPATH";

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -verbose:gc";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseG1GC"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCDetails";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseCompressedOops";
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError";

MAIN_CLASS="App"

nohup java -classpath $CLASSPATH $JVM_OPTS $MAIN_CLASS "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null &


Show us your build.sbt file and tell us which command you run precisely.
